# Omit selected value from function output

Tags: r

I need to hide from the output a particular value of a function, i can't find the way to do it.

For example if i run a Shapiro-Wilk test i want to hide the W value and print all the remaining ones. I know you can print only a specific value using the $, is there a similar command which specifically hides one value?

Example
Normal output

```
Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:data1
W = 0.94771, p-value = 0.1349
```

What i want

```
Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:data1
p-value = 0.1349
```

Comment: Most objects in R are just vectors or matrices.  You can try `test[ ]' for identifying specific things in the test.  Without sample data we can't help you though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
test <- shapiro.test(rnorm(100, mean = 5, sd = 3))

test[2]

> $p.value
  [1] 0.3542693

# For your desired output:

cat(paste(test[3], '\n', "p-value =", test[2])

> Shapiro-Wilk normality test 
  p-value = 0.354269315676623
```